# CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity is NULL, despite initializing and setting the activity

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to use Montemagno's [CrossCurrentActivity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) plugin to resolve the current activity in a Xamarin.Forms.Android project. However, `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity` is always null. What am I doing wrong?

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();                        
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);    

            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
            // CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity is NULL
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;
            // CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity is still NULL

            var formsApp = new App(new AndroidInitializer());
            _registryContainer = formsApp.Container;    
            LoadApplication(formsApp);
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

Do not set `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity` yourself:
<strike>`CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;`</strike>

According to [github project](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) you could init `CrossCurrentActivity` in `MainActivity.cs`:
`CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);`

Alternatively you could init it in [application level](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin#application-level).

Comment: Only using the Application level approach worked for me. The code added to the MainActivity had no effect, I could remove without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and this is what I added to my MainActivity.cs inside OnCreate method

```
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
CrossFingerprint.SetCurrentActivityResolver(() => CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

On MainActivity.cs inside OnCreate method add this:

```java
Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```